# Reindex'ing activestorage images in elasticsearch errors with `stack level too deep`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-6, searchkick

Trying to reindex activestorage images in elasticsearch and it's erroring with `searchkick:reindex SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
  searchkick
end
```

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product                             ✔ 
Reindexing Product...

rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep

home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:33:in `block in match'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:33:in `each'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:33:in `find'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:33:in `match'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:10:in `respond_to_missing?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:129:in `respond_to?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.4.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:129:in `respond_to_missing?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:305:in `respond_to?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:305:in `respond_to_missing?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:55:in `respond_to?'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:55:in `as_json'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:175:in `block in as_json'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:174:in `each'
/home/sufyan/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:174:in `as_json'
```

Comment: The error is indicative of an infinite loop, something related to trying to call `as_json`. Your stacktrace is insufficient to see where it starts/repeats. Can you include the `image` class?

Comment: Can you reproduce it by calling `as_json` on a product?

Comment: yes it is the same error   class ProductsController < ApplicationController
     
      def index
        products = Product.all
        render json: products,  status: 200
      end

Comment: but resolved by adding" include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent" and       "  render json: products, include: [images: { methods: :service_url }], status: 200"

Comment: but I have no idea how to searchkick handle it and how to render images by searchkick